# Spark Custom DataSource

Tags: apache-spark

so I'm writting a custom Data Source for reading some data from hbase. Everything fine until ExistingRDD.rowToRowRdd get's call. Then it tries to get the schema from my GenericRowWithSchema. It fails  I have no ideia why... I saw people having similar problems on the past. I'm on Spark 1.6.3 and my schema is fixed to :

```
    StructType(Seq(StructField("Date", LongType),
        StructField("Device", StringType),
        StructField("Tag", StringType),
        StructField("TagValue", DoubleType))
    )

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): scala.MatchError: 1451610000 (of class java.lang.Long)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:56)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:86)
```

Any ideias ?

Answer (score 1):

So I find out why. On override def buildScan(requiredColumns: Array[String], filters: Array[Filter]): RDD[Row] = {....}
your Row need to have exact that requiredColumns